# Material UI notch above label is too small, any way to override?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

[image: The notch thingy too small]

The notch is too small for my text,
and I wanted to override the InputLabel properties to better support it. I'm using `shrink` to keep the label stuck on top even if there isn't a value, but I don't know how to change that components props to accommodate the big size label. Here's what I have so far:

```
      <FormControl sx={{ width: 400, mt: 1 }} size="small">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="outlined-adornment-re-enter-password">
          Re-enter Password
        </InputLabel>
        <OutlinedInput
          notched
          id="outlined-adornment-re-enter-password"
          type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange("password")}
          endAdornment={
            <InputAdornment position="end">
              <IconButton
                aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                edge="end"
              >
                {values.showPassword ? (
                  <VisibilityOff />
                ) : (
                  <Visibility />
                )}
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          }
          label="Password"
        />
      </FormControl>
```

I've tried tinkering with InputLabel by switching `notched` between different components as a last ditch effort but to no avail. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: https://mui.com/api/outlined-input/ says that the "label" option is used for layout, but the actual label comes from LabelInput.  So looks like "label" needs to be the same size as LabelInput.  I don't use reactjs so this is just from the doc.

Comment: Consider using TextField component, it handles 80% of the common use cases.

Comment: Thanks, it was way easier setting up textField since I could use the property `InputProps` and add the adornment there.